# Retrieve ExperienceBundle not working for one Community but working for another

Tags: community, salesforcedx, lightning-community, salesforcedx-cli

I should say at the start, I'm not very experienced with Communities.

I'm struggling to find a problem with retrieving the source of a Lightning Community as ExperienceBundle. I've activated the ExperienceBundle Metadata API setting in Communities Settings.

When looking though the Org Browser I can see the 2 Communities we have in the org, but downloading only ever retrieves one of them. I tried source:retrieve using -m and -p and both only for for one of the communities. I tried activating the setting and retrieving from multiple Sandboxes with the same problems.

[image]

Even though I can see the community listed in the ExperienceBundles in the OrgBrowser, if I tried to retrieve the result is "no results found". While doing the same for the other community does work.

[image]

The only difference I see is that the one community which I can retrieve is in "preview" and the one which I cannot is "active". But even after activating both communities, the same problem continues. The communities are both Lightning Community with the same Template.
In the OrgBrowser view I can see that one of them is showing up as **COMMUNITY_NAME1** (downloads ok) and **COMMUNITY_NAME_C** (doesn't download).

The below note in the docs makes me suspicuous, but I can't figure out whether that's the issue. The community I am able to download does indeed specifiy "ChatterNetworkPicasso" in the meta.xml file. But I'm not sure how to find out for the one I don't manage to download, whether that's the case. Anything that I can see seems to be the same for both the communities. (Site, Network, going though the builder and workspaces, ..)
[image]

Looking into retrieved sites, both the corresponsing sites have `<siteType>ChatterNetwork</siteType>`.

The SiteDotCom meta file for the community looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SiteDotCom xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>COMMUNITY_NAME</label>
    <siteType>ChatterNetworkPicasso</siteType>
</SiteDotCom>
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: I can retrieve the 3 communities in my org and one has the 1 format name and the other 2 have the _C format name. What happens if you just retrieve the metadata type `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ExperienceBundle` and don't specify? For me, it even warns me about my old sites I have that the ExperienceBundle Metadata API doesn't support.

Comment: Interesting point. I get a list of the dowloaded artifacts for one of the communities and a warning message 

=== WARNING: The following metadata isn’t in your org. If it’s not new, someone deleted it from the org.
An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 71801796-836665 (-1430610014)

Comment: Ah, I'd definitely provide that to Salesforce support if you're able to. It's possible there's some sort of bug or issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to resolve this issue with the help of Salesforce support. Turns out it's a bug related to the TabSet component. These are the steps to resolve (or rather a workaround) as provided by support:

> This behavior is observed when there is any Tabset components in
> reference.
>
> To fix this please check the below workaround as suggested until the
> bug is fixed.
>
> 1. Drag and drop a new tabset component to the page and then manually moving the components within each tab of the old tabset component to
>    the new tabset component
> 2. Make sure the new tabset component's tabs have the same configuration as the old tabset component (e.g. Publically available
>    checkbox)
> 3. Make sure the new tabset component has the same audience assignments as the old one if an audience was assigned.
> 4. Manually update the tab names for each language within Experience Builder by using the language switcher on the top right corner of the
>    header.
>
> Please note that if this workaround is used, DO NOT export languages &
> reimport them because it's the importing of languages that causes the
> bad data to be inserted for the tabset component.

Apparently, there is no public record of this (known issue or that)

UPDATE 2020-07-01
Had some issues with this again where even the workaround didn't help. But the underlying bug is apparently getting fixed with the Summer '20 release.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you're trying to retrieve single metadata elements by name.

1. Did you try to retrieve these files with `package.xml`?

   `sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest
   /.../manifest/package-workfile.xml`

   These are elements I have in my `package.xml` and Experience Bundle is retrieved when in VSCode I right-click on a manifest file to retrieve it:

   *CustomSite*


       
       ExperienceBundle


       *
       Network

   [image]
2. Maybe the other community you see in community pages is not a Lightning Community - just some kind of an old Site.com legacy??? I'm just guessing, but maybe it's worth making sure the other community you're trying to retrieve is in fact an Experience Bundle in terms of metadata.

Comment: Same result with the manifest export, only one of them is retrieved.

I can't really find any difference between them. Both say Lightning Community, but have the Customer Service template. Both say ChatterNetworkPicasso in the SiteDotCome meta file. 

The difference is the _C at the end and the fact that the one that doesn't work was originally created back in 2017, while the one that does in 2019 (and ends in 1 instead of _C)